# How to detect iPhone device flattened usig camera

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion, avcapturedevice

I am trying to detect the device flattened to the surface to take pictures like the native camera. Like below Screenshot
[image: Native camera]

I tried using CMMotionManager,

```
      let motioManager = CMMotionManager()
       motioManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.2
         
        if (motioManager.isAccelerometerAvailable){
            motioManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(
                to: OperationQueue.current!,
                withHandler: {(accelData: CMAccelerometerData?, errorOC: Error?) in
                    self.outputAccelData(acceleration: accelData!.acceleration)
                })
        }
```

```
    
        if  acceleration.x > -0.1 && acceleration.x > -0.1   {
            
            if  acceleration.y < 0.1 && acceleration.y < 0.1 {
 
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn) {
                    
                    self.centerLabel.frame.origin.x = self.screen.midX-20
                    self.centerLabel.frame.origin.y = self.screen.midY-20
                } completion: { [self] done in

}
```

But I am not getting a smooth output. Could anyone help me out with how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance
[image: Out put view]

Comment: Instead of using Accelerometer data, I would suggest you use `gravity` in `CMDeviceMotion`

Comment: @VisalRajapakse Thanks for the reply. Could you suggest how to achieve it using gravity?